# Upgrading Wine on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine, playonlinux

**Synopsis**
I am running Ubuntu 18.04.
I am trying to install a Windows program using PlayOnLinux and want to use the latest stable Wine version (5.0), as I am having problems with the current version of Wine I am using. On PlayOnLinux I can see the latest version I have available is 3.20. I could not figure out how to get Wine 5.0 on PlayOnLinux so I decided to try to install it separately.
Currently when running `wine --version` I get `wine-3.6 (Ubuntu 3.6-1)`

**What I Tried**
I couldn't figure out how to upgrade the wine version so I just tried to install Wine 5.0 on top of what I had currently.
I tried following multiple tutorials but this one was the main one I tried: https://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu/

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

But I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried using aptitude to deal with dependencies:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
```

And after it installing things I got:

```
Current status: 73 (-5) upgradable.
```

(Not sure if this is a good result or not)
Then I tried installing again using `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable` but got the same results as before. All the time still checking the wine version and seeing it has not been changed.

I tried removing wine using `sudo apt remove wine` and `sudo apt-get purge wine` but what I get is `Virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed`. I have found some forums that indicated I need to start removing files or dependencies manually, but those came with a lot of warnings and did not find anyone approving that it worked for them so I was too scared to try them out on my system.

**What I want to happen**
I want to be able to use Wine 5.0, preferably through PlayOnLinux, but that is not a must. I would prefer not to have to remove the other versions of Wine I have installed as I have other programs installed using them, but if the only way to do it is by removing all of Wine I will do it, but I need instructions on how to do that as what I found is not working for me.

Thanks in advance for any help available.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Unfortunately this did not help. I followed the instructions but still when I run `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable` I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Do you have any repositories pointing to eoan in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?  Or any in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder?  It should be trying to install wine from bionic or the Suse.  What is the output of `apt-cache madison winehq-stable` show?  Edit your question and add the output there.  It is hard to read it when you add it to the comments here.

Comment: I cant believe it! I had a line in /etc/apt/sources.list for eoan which I guess I copied from a tutorial for a different Ubuntu version. I removed it and now it seems to be installing. My internet is super slow, so it will take time to see if it succeeds, but seems good for now. Thank you so much! I will let you know if it succeeds and if so you are more than welcome to post this as an answer and I Will approve it happily.

Comment: It Worked, but it upgraded me to wine 4.0.4, not 5.0, I assume because the post you referenced me to was a bit older. I am now removing the Suse repo and trying the one from my tutorial for 5.0 and seeing if it works, and will report back with final results. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, so after removing the old Wine repos from `/etc/apt/sources.list` the tutorial I linked in my post works and will install Wine 5.0. Officially the other post you gave didn't solve my problem on its own, only you telling me to check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove any eoan wine repos helped. @Terrance would you like to post that as an answer and I will approve it?

Comment: Done, I also retracted that link and the close vote.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It appears that there is a repo for Eoan (Ubuntu 19.10) configured and that is where it is trying to install `winehq-stable` from.  Since your system is running Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) remove any `wine` repo lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` that have `eoan` in their name and re-run `sudo apt update` then try your installation again.

Comment: Just to clarify, I removed any wine repos that had eoan from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then I redid everything in the tutorial in my original post and it worked!
Thank you so much again!

Comment: @OhaNoch Updated to say wine.  Thank you!  =)